# How to make a link so that clicking it fires a GET but do not open up a window

Tags: javascript, http, hyperlink

In my current implementetion of two-factor auth, I'm sending a SMS to the user with a link. When the link is clicked, the login proceedes on the users machine.

However, on the phone the browser will open up a empty page (since I'm currently returning 204 from the webserver for the link clicked in the SMS.

What I would like to happen is that when the user clicks the link in the SMS, the broser is not opened at all. It should just send the GET request, and the user will not have to close the browser window on his phone.

If that is not possible, is it possible to make the window that get's opened to autoclose imediately?

Comment: How would I do that on a link inside the SMS that is only plain text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser has to open to make the request.  There's nothing you can do about this.

However, if you control the content from the web server, you can attempt a `window.close()` on-load.  Realistically, you'll probably get blocked on this and should also have a fallback content that says something like, "logged in, please close this window".  (You can probably call `window.close()` on a button click.)

Comment: Yes, I was afraid that this was the only possibility. But showing some content with a button that calls `window.close()`might actually bypass the block. I will try this out later and let you know.

Comment: This answers the question. However, `window.close()` will not help here since it only allows closing a window that was previously opened by javascript as well (in most browsers)